# Can a conductor be uniformly charged if charges tend to reside on the surface?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

As per the title, I'm thinking if it is possible to have a conducting metallic solid sphere with uniform charge distribution if the charges in a conductor tend to distribute themselves on the surface of the conductor.

Comment: It could have a uniform (net) charge of 0. Normally when we have problems that assume a uniform charge in some region, we shouldn't assume that region is a conductor.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. This can be shown by applying the following equations at any point inside the conductor:
$$-\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = \nabla\cdot\mathbf{J} \\ \mathbf{J}=\sigma\mathbf{E} \\ \nabla\cdot\mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
so that
$$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \rho$$
Therefore all charge in a conductor will move to the surface (and in a short amount of time, since $\sigma/\epsilon_0 \sim 10^{19}\, s^{-1}$ for typical conductors).

Comment: Do you mean $10^{-19}$ s? Because if not, that would be a couple of million millennia ;)